# Bootstrap 3 navbar two different backgrounds

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

How can I customize the bootstrap 3 navbar that will look like this, with different backgrounds?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the default navbar or a full-width navbar (fixed/static)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy: just make 2 divs of that width and make them float to right and left + change background color

example:

> .left {
> float: left;
> background-color: blue;}
>
> .right {
> float: right;
> background-color: silver; }

html:

```
> <div class="left">CONTENT GOES HERE</div> <div class="right">CONTENT
> GOES HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fit a div to the content you want to customize and put a background-color in it. Or even the < li >'s themselves.

A little bit of your code would help.